# Can't pass a parameter through onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a Counter component that has two buttons and a counter. One button increases the counter and the other decreases it. I don't want to create two separate onClick handlers so I'm trying to pass a parameter through the onClick. The thing is I can't access it afterwards in the handler function since it's undefined.

**Counter Component**

```
import Button from './Button.jsx';

function Counter() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const increaseLabel = 'Increase';
    const decreseLabel = 'Decrese';

    function clickHandler(e) {
        const currentLabel = e.target.label;
        console.log(e.target) // <button label="Increase">Increase</button>
        console.log(e.target.label) // undefined

        if (currentLabel === increaseLabel) {
            setCount(count + 1)
        } else {
            setCount(count - 1)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button label={increaseLabel} onClick={clickHandler} />
            <Button label={decreseLabel} onClick={clickHandler} />
            <br/>
            <h2>{count}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Button Component**

```
import React from 'react';

function Button(props) {
    const label = props.label;
    return (
        <button label={label} onClick={props.onClick}>{label}</button>
    ) 
}

export default Button;
```

Any idea on how I can access the parameter from within the handler?

Comment: `e.target.getAttribute('label')`?

Comment: @dave Yes! Thanks! Is this really the way to do something like this or is there a better way?

Comment: You really shouldn't be checking the label, that's going to be a nightmare if you ever change it and forget that other places in your code check.  I would definitely have either two functions, or do something like `onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e, 'increment'))}`

Comment: I'd probably even just do `onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pointing onClick to `clickHandler` directly, you can wrap it in an anonymous function, which will allow you to supply a second argument to your `clickHandler` function:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <Button label={increaseLabel} onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e, "foo")} />
            <Button label={decreaseLabel} onClick={(e) => clickHandler(e, "bar")} />
            <br/>
            <h2>{count}</h2>
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @dave, depending on the `label` as an attribute is not so nice but since you are passing it as a prop you don't need to struggle with `event` but instead, you can use this prop in your click handler of your `button` and pass it back to `clickHandler` function.

```js
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const increase = "Increase";
  const decrease = "Decrese";

  function clickHandler(type) {
    return type === increase
      ? setCount((prev) => prev + 1)
      : setCount((prev) => prev - 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button label={increase} onClick={clickHandler} />
      <Button label={decrease} onClick={clickHandler} />
      <br />
      <h2>{count}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Button({ label, onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={() => onClick(label)}>{label}</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```